# ¿Cómo recargar los componentes de la clase Character en Unreal Engine 5.3 con blue prints tras la carga sin usar un proyecto en C++?

Tags: c++, unreal-engine

El problema concretamente nos lo está causando un plugin únicamente: el constructor de caracteres para Metahumanos de Polyphoria, aunque en teoría es aplicable a la carga de cualquier componente dentro de una clase o sublase (clase heredada o similar)  ¿Cómo volver a cargar los componentes del plugin Polyphoria en Unreal Engine 5 dentro de la clase Character (a su vez dentro de otras clase, claro) para un juego multijugador sin usar c++?

Estamos programando un juego multijugador basado (es un juego social con una imagen hiperrealista como el antiguo Second Life) utilizando únicamente niveles porque el sistema de red es muy sencillo, y utilizando metahumanos. Usamos el plugin de creación de personajes de Polyphoria para metahumanos.

¡Y algo realmente extraño sucede! Añadimos todos los componentes a las clase "Character" (añadimos una subclase llamada BPCharacter donde ponemos todos los componentes necesarios del plugin Polyphoria), luego compilamos y ¡ya está todo OK! pero... ¡sorpresa!

Pero luego cuando probamos el programa en ordenadores, el 75% de las veces carga y todo correcto, pero ¡el 25% no carga a tiempo los componentes dentro de BPCharacter! y solo en clientes, ¡nunca en el ordenador que crea la sesión! Así que resumiendo, no carga el constructor/selector de personajes de Polyphoria.

El problema es evidente y vemos que solo ocurre o en ordenadores un poco lentos o cuando la conexión es un poco lenta (lo hemos probado en más de 50 ordenadores diferentes y unas 20 líneas de conexión diferentes, desde fibra hasta 4G).

Parece obvio que en algunas circunstancias no carga completamente todos los componentes implementados en BPCharacter (dentro de la clase Character). Hemos visto que este problema le ocurre a más gente en los foros de Unreal pero a través de blueprints nadie da soluciones, aunque se podría extender a cualquier componente que no cargara. La solución más sencilla es recargar todos los componentes de la clase que fallan. ¡Eso es fácil usando un proyecto Unreal Engine con C++! ¡Pero con Blueprints no encontramos la manera!

Hemos optimizado el escenario al máximo, materiales, instanciación, etc., desactivado Nanite y Lumen, etc. Es decir, carga muy rápido, es un entorno muy sencillo y optimizado por niveles. De hecho, cuando el constructor carga y el metahumano funciona, (el 75% aproximandamente de las veces) ¡el resto del juego va realmente perfecto! (chat de voz, luces, interacciones, animación de personajes, etc) Así que... ¡Todos los blueprints, componentes, plugins (estamos hablando de más de 1000!) funcionan perfectamente!... ¡excepto el plugin polyphoria que a veces no carga o carga incorrectamente y no aparece el selector/constructor de personajes!

Dado como compila Unreal Engine la clase Character, no se puede cambiar su punto de ejecución, si algún componente falla en la carga, (tiene narices, ¡solo falla los relacionados con polyphoria entre cientos!) ya no se puede ejecutar el constructor y no hay nada que hacer, se debe cerrar y reiniciar el programa.

Un proyecto creado en C++ y migrar todo es la solución sencilla pero costaría meses y horas de trabajo por un solo plugin. Además, todo funciona de maravilla cuando no falla la carga y está plenamente testeado. Así que la cuestión es cómo forzar desde un proyecto basado en blueprints a que recargue los componentes en un subclase de Character una vez iniciada la conexión de red. (Otra solución, claro, es que no cargue un componente hasta que no verifique que el previo ha cargado satisfactoriamente y reinicie la carga. Pero con blueprints no se nos ocurre como hacer eso y que realmente funcione, desde C++ obviamente no es problema)

¿Quizás se nos ha pasado algo inadvertido y la causa está en otro punto diferente? ¿Podemos hablar de realizar una carga "asíncrona" de módulos en C++ pero... ¿cómo conseguimos una recarga efectiva de componentes de la clase Character en blueprints porque el problema, si lo extendemos puede afectar a muchos juegos en red diseñados solo con un proyecto con blueprints? Insisto en que cuando el ordenador es muy potente y la conexión de red va perfecta SIEMPRE se carga y ejecuta todos los componentes sin problemas.

Hemos pensado que el problema podría estar en la configuración del servidor tanto usando Epic Online o EOS Core y cambiando los parámetros o eliminando limitaciones (
MaxNetTickRate, NetServerMaxTickRate, LanServerMaxTickRate, ClientTicksPerSecond, MaxInternetClientRate, etc., etc.)

En modo SandBox todo funciona perfectamente, la replicación cuando carga bien todo es inmaculada... Incluso cuando bajamos la calidad de la línea "artificialmente" todo se limita a que los avatares u otros objetos actualizan con "delay" pero poco más, ni craseos ni nada de nada. Así que el problema es difícil de achacar al sistema de Epic.

¿Alguna solución al problema?

> Nos ha sorprendido la incapacidad del equipo de asistencia de Epic (y si hemos mandado la copia para licenciar, estamos registrados, etc.) o por parte de Polyphoria de resolver el problema, (lo curioso es que en foros hemos encontrado a más equipos con este problema cuando usan este constructor en red, nunca off-line y no pocos).

Hemos repasado uno a uno, en torno a los 80 componentes de polyphoria para encontrar el extraño problema. (Lo hemos modificado, pero el problema se repite exactamente igual si usamos los componentes "intactos").

Más allá solo queda meses de migración a un proyecto sobre C++ y ¡cientos o miles de horas de reprogramación!

> Usar stackoverflow es una de las últimas opciones que nos quedan antes de migrar con la locura de trabajo que supondría.

Comment: No puedo ayudar tanto porque conozco poco de Unreal pero, por qué deberían migrar todo a C++? Si encontraron una solución en C++, deberían poder [combinar blueprints y C++](https://dev.epicgames.com/community/learning/tutorials/YDpo/mixing-blueprints-and-c), con la solución en C++.

Comment: Me temo que no es posible Mateo, para poder alterar las secuencias de carga o recargar un módulo, solo es posible en la práctica programándolo en C++, tu puedes llamar a código c++ (en realidad todo Unreal son "clases" y "herencias" por si así lo entiendes) muchos componentes llaman a c++. Pero tu no puedes cambiar el orden de carga de la clase "Character" y sus subclases y componentes. Si el proyecto no es en c++ imposible (hasta donde sabemos) y por narices los componentes de Polyphoria deben estar en la clase "Character"(eso lo hemos ido descubriendo con el tiempo, blueprint es muy limitado

Comment: @Mateo, cuando digo que el sistema de blueprints es limitado no quiero que se malinterprete, se pueden ahorrar miles de horas de programación con este sistema de scripts visual, además hay plugins a cansar que ahorran trabajo en la tienda por poco dinero,  pero es tremendamente limitado para generar un control de un "core" con un tamaño que no sea muy pequeño si trabajas en un multijugador. (Eso que dicers es lo que pensamos nosotros hace varios años tras trabajar en proyectos más pequeños con solo blueprints que era más rápido que usar c# en Unity)

Comment: BPCharacter es algo que crearon ustedes o viene con Polyphoria? Y respecto a los componentes, cómo es la *recarga*, debe suceder una sola vez desde el editor o cada que corre el juego? Me gustaría poder ayudarles más pero sé muy poco de Unreal y no conozco Polyphoria. Solo puedo intentar ayudar desde lo que sé de C++.

Comment: Por si sirve de algo, revisaron estos link? https://wiki.polyphoria.com/en/tutorials/package-project-for-singleplayer https://wiki.polyphoria.com/en/tutorials/package-project-for-multiplayer

Comment: Gracias Mateo, pero si,  hemos leído toda la documentación de arriba a bajo  (de hecho el 1er enlace que me pones referencia al single player y el segundo es para una compilación desde C++ con importación de mapas) que es al final lo que acabaremos haciendo y queremos evitar. BPCharacter es una clase que añadimos nosotros a la clase Character (por lo de Blueprint pues BP).  Sigue (1/2)

Comment: (2/3)Respecto a la recarga de los componentes de polyphoria, como comento en la pregunta, la recarga solo sería necesaria de manera redundante (al iniciar el juego o después al entrar en el modo de red) la cuestión es que falla la carga de algún componente de polyphoria (a veces) dentro de la clase y desde BPs es imposible recargar si ha fallado (UE5 carga múltiples módulos a la vez, con un proyecto c++  ya sabes que se puede controlar pero solo con un proyecto BP no hay llamada a C++ que resuelva la carga... (sigue abajo)

Comment: (3/3) ...de la clase o de los componentes de polyphoria -que sepamos y funcione ) De todas maneras, gracias por intentar ayudarnos y encantado de conocerte, siempre es de agradecer conocer a otro programador de C++

Comment: No entiendo cómo no es posible hacer las partes problemáticas en C++ y el resto con blueprints. Te dejo un par de links por si te sirven. https://youtu.be/VMZftEVDuCE https://docs.unrealengine.com/5.0/en-US/cpp-and-blueprints-example/

Comment: Gracias Mateo, pero no le des vueltas, el problema no va por ahí, puedes añadir todo lo que quieras en c++ pero me temo que no comprendes cómo son las clases de Unreal que conforman el motor y dónde se deben alojar en un clase concreta los componentes de Polyphoria (o sea las herencias), cuando lo basas solo en un proyecto en BPs, hay algo en el código que hicieron que causa el fallo (quizás en alguno de sus componentes en C++, una variable, etc ... A saber) ya te dije que no hay forma de forzar la recarga de la clase character si falla en un proyecto de BPs (si la hay, eso es lo que buscamos)

Comment: De todas maneras Mateo, gracias por el Interés, pero al final estamos migrando el proyecto a otro en C++ donde podamos controlar todo el proceso de carga en EOS y verificar la carga en ordenadores con conexión lenta, ya hemos visto que nadie sabe en BP iniciar de nuevo la clase Character en caso de un retraso en el cliente. (La propia Epic aconseja al final pasar el proyecto a uno cpp, así que al final blanco y en botella... Unos meses más de machaque) un saludo

Comment: Que pena que no haya una mejor solución. Que les vaya bien.